# Forced validations for associated fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5.0.0.1

When I submit a form, validations for associated fields are coming into action.

I have **Gig**, **User**, **Category** and other models

I am using **devise** for user authentication

***Gig model***

```
class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proposals
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :abilities
  has_many :skills, through: :abilities
  belongs_to :user
end
```

***User model***

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :gigs
  has_many :proposals
end
```

***Category model***

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gigs
end
```

When I try to create the gig in console, the transaction rolls back.

the error messages are

> ["Category must exist", "User must exist"]

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you post the complete contents of gig.rb?

Comment: Yes, this is standard in rails 5.  What's the problem?  Why include controller and view informationin in this post if the issue is in rails console?

Comment: Thank you. I don't know it is standard. I recently upgraded to rails 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails 5 when you add belongs_to it makes this field required. Try this

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```